# C# : Improved my failing regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have an array with five values :

```
    "-360°"
    "0 x"
    "1r"
    "0,01 m/s"
    "0,01 m/s²"
```

I want to extract all units related string.

I have this regex :

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\-0-9\.\,0-90-9]+)(\s*)([°\w])");
```

But with m/s and m/s², I can't extract them.

Could you help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The matter is `\w` doesn't include `/`. You could just include / into your regex.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\-0-9\.\,0-90-9]+)(\s*)([°\w\/²]*)");
```

or more basically

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\-0-9\.\,0-90-9]+)(\s*)([^""]*)");
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a simple quote mark after the ^. Regards

Comment: This can be reduced to `new Regex(@"([0-9\.,-]+)(\s*)([^\"]*)");` if it is always of type "<number><unity>"

Comment: @Rik: `\"` should be `""` in a verbatim string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you have contains a basic issue: you want to match an integer or a float number using a character class. `[\-0-9\.\,0-90-9]` matches 1 character, either `-`, `0-9`, `.`, or  `,` 1 or more times. You really just need `(-?\d*,?\d+)` to match such a number.

Since you need to match superscript or subscript characters, you can use the corresponding range `[\u2070-\u209F\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3]` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts)).

Here is an updated regex that can match ⁰, ¹, ², ³, ⁴, ⁵, ⁶, ⁷, ⁸, ⁹, ⁿ, etc.

```
(-?\d*,?\d+)(\s*)([°\w](?:/[\w\u2070-\u209F\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3]+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(-%3F%5Cd*%2C%3F%5Cd%2B)(%5Cs*)(%5B%C2%B0%5Cw%5D(%3F%3A%2F%5B%5Cw%5Cu2070-%5Cu209F%5Cu00B9%5Cu00B2%5Cu00B3%5D%2B)%3F)&i=-360%C2%B0%0D%0A0%20x%0D%0A1r%0D%0A0%2C01%20m%2Fs%0D%0A0%2C01%20m%2Fs%C2%B2)

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/EqoTdd):

```
var lines = new string[] {"-360°", "0 x", "1r", "0,01 m/s", "0,01 m/s²"};
foreach (var s in lines) 
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"(-?\d*,?\d+)(\s*)([°\w](?:/[\w\u2070-\u209F\u00B9\u00B2\u00B3]+)?)");
    foreach (Match m in matches) {
        Console.WriteLine("Match:" + m.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Group[1]: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Group[2]: " + m.Groups[2].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Group[3]: " + m.Groups[3].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope my answer is quite clear, if you have any further doubts, please feel free to drop a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([\-0-9\.\,0-90-9]+)(\s*)([°\w\/²])");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can reduce your regex to:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[-0-9.,]+\s*([°\w/²]*)");
```